# MYSQL - Using SUM with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Ok, so I have 4 tables.

A `users` table with columns `id` and `name`.

A `groups` table with columns `id`, `name` and `owner`.

A `items` table with columns `group` and `content`.

A `content` table with columns `id`, `name` and `duration`.

Each user can have several groups. Each group can have several items inside it. Each item represents one of the pieces of content.

I want to be able to list all the groups, **with a sum of all durations of each piece of content inside that group**.

What Ive been trying is this:

```
select groups.id,groups.name,users.name,sum(content.duration) as duration from groups
join users on groups.owner=users.id
join items on items.group=groups.id
join content on content.id=items.content
```

Unfortunately this only gives me one result, with a total sum of all the durations of each piece of content in all of the groups - like so:

```
"g001", "Group 1", "Me", "400"
```

What I am expecting is something like:

```
"g001", "Group 1", "Me", "160"
"g002", "Group 2", "You", "160"
"g003", "Group 3", "Them", "80"
```

Comment: can u give some simple data?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this

```
   select groups.id,groups.name,users.name,sum(content.duration) as duration from groups
   join users on groups.owner=users.id
   join items on items.group=groups.id
   join content on content.id=items.content
   group by groups.name
```

Comment: you welcome ! i wanted confirm by simple data if u gave me :) to show u on sqlfiddle demo. good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select groups.id,groups.name,users.name,sum(content.duration) as duration
from groups
    join users
        on groups.owner=users.id
    join items
        on items.group=groups.id
    join content
        on content.id=items.content
group by groups.id,groups.name,users.name
```

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` allows you to display all groups even without content but the total value of the `duration` will be *zero.*

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name GroupName, 
        d.name OwnerName,
        SUM(c.duration) totals
FROM    groups a
        INNER JOIN users d
            ON a.owner = d.id
        LEFT JOIN items b
            ON a.id = b.group
        LEFT JOIN content c
            ON b.content = c.id
GROUP   BY a.id, a.name, d.name
```